# WAMP Server 2.2 - .htaccess -> Internal error (500)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I've just added an `.htaccess` and an `.htpasswd` to my web app and i'm now getting an error 500.

.htaccess :

```
AuthUserFile ./.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic

<limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</limit>
```

.htpasswd

```
root:roe7nCYHcm0As
```

I've read on this web site that i had to enable "**headers_module**" and "**rewrite_module**" and then retart the server, which i did, but i'm still getting this error.

I'm using wampserver 2.2 (apache 2.4.2) on windows 7.

Comment: Have you configured your apache configuration? You should change AllowOverride None to All.

Comment: Yep, it was already set to all.

Comment: Could this e the problem : `Could not open password file: C:/Program Files/Wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/.htpasswd` ? Maybe i need to put an absolute path ?

Comment: Well absolute path does not work either.

Comment: Please check this link: http://www.lifeofapleskadmin.com/2010/03/create-htaccess-file-on-a-wamp-system/

Comment: Well i tried it, but it does not work. I also tried enclosing the absolute path in double quotes, and it does ask for my password, but it fails even if i enter the right password.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP so there is no need for the tag. Also, please leave out the fluff like "thanks" and "any ideas?" from your question.

Answer (score 1):

That's most probably because htaccess does not find your file's location.

If you use a relative path, then apache uses the server root which is `/etc/apache2` in my case (ubuntu).

Just to be sure, click right on the password file and get the path and paste it to .htaccess. If it still not works, please copy and paste your error log here so that I can exactly see the error.

**EDIT**

I've seen your last comment now.

Some setups require that you store the encrypted version of the password. So for instance, instead of storing the password as

```
myuser:111
```

you should store like:

```
myuser:$apr1$E6YrxcHU$ilyC2mqfNSrQmle4KEAeq.
```

I don't have a Windows at hand right now so I cannot check it but earlier versions of Wamp had a password generator for .htpasswd under `c:\wamp\Apache2\bin\htpasswd.exe`. Try to check that program.

Otherwise, apache uses md5 by default to encrypt passwords. You can encrypt programmatically your password and then copy it to the password file.

[I even blogged about this](http://vsk.me/en/25/protect-folders-using-htaccess) :)

Please let me know if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it could well be that you have installed wamp into 'program files'

There are a few bits of Apache and PHP that dont like living in a folder structure that has a space in one of the folder names.

It is recommended that you install it to C:\wamp or D:\wamp or any drive you like but not one with a space in any folder name.